# MATLAB Report Generator

Tags: matlab

I am creating requirement reports for MATLAB model using Report generator tool in MATLAB. For that, I am fetching requirement data for requirement.doc word document. Requirement data in word file are in the form of different bullets style. While creating the report in HTML format, all data coming in single line. Data from the word file is not pasting in HTML report file in their original format.

How to retain the same format in the final report?